# What is next in the sequence of dot arrangements?

Tags: visual, sequence

Given the 3 arrangements, identify the next in sequence. [image: there]

Reference: Book on Quantitative Ability and Puzzles for Competitive Exams, India.

I have the correct answer, will edit the question once it has been solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only one of the four options that is consistent with the first three is:

> C

Because:

> There is one white circle in each row, and it is never adjacent to any black circle in the same row. C is the only one of the available options that continues this pattern.

There may be something I am missing though:

> I can't really see a sequence here. C is just one of many possible patterns that meet the rule I've found. I can't see a logical progression that would lead from the first three patterns to C specifically.